# Lettuce can't figure out multilevel replication topology

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I have a situation where I have got the following setup: Redis A (Master) -> Redis B (Slave of A) -> Redis C (Slave of B). And I'mconfiguring redis template for this topology.  When you specify a host of either master (A) or slave(B) in Lettuce Master-Slave configuration it will work but when I specify IP of C it breaks with the following exception.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Redis exception; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot determine a node to read (Known nodes: []) with setting io.lettuce.core.ReadFromImpl$ReadFromSlave@4b80c7ea
```

This is the error I get when I hit actuator/health endpoint against that connectionFactory bean of the redis with status being "DOWN".

Is it that Lettuce can't detect master in such multilevel situations and if so, even if I specify IP of A will it be able to discover "C"?  Can someone tell what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Lettuce doesn't support topology discovery for multi-level redis setup.  [Find the Github issue here](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/1042)